# Triggering navigation while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to modify my navigation links depending on the section currently scrolled over by the user.

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="#resume">Resume</a>
    <a href="#design">Design</a>
    <a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

and the following structure

```
<section id="resume">my content</section>
<section id="design">....
```

In order to achieve the effect I'm using the tutorial presented [here](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2012/01/triggering-navigation-with-scrolling-in-jquery/) which works really well for the smooth scrolling but doesn't add any class to my navigation links.

Would you be able to help understand why?

Thanks a lot,
Julien

Comment: Maybe add the code you are using to add the classes? Also, check out this page where I did the same: https://castoredc.com/nl/tour.html it was quite tricky but it works, although not entirely smooth for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

CSS

```css
.navigation { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; background-color:#88f; }
.navigation a { margin:2em; color:white; text-decoration:none; }
.navigation a.active {text-decoration:underline; color:red;}
#resume { margin-top:50px; }
section { margin:2em; height:500px; background-color:#eee; }
```

jQuery

```js
$(function(){
    var links = $('.navigation>a'); //.not('.contact');
    var sections = $('section');
    links.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var p = $(this.getAttribute('href')).position().top;
        $("html, body").stop().animate( { scrollTop: (p-30)+'px' }, 500);
    });
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
        var i=0;
        sections.each(function(j){
            var br = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            if (br.top<150) { // distance from the top of screen
                i = j;
            }
        });
        var scrollBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollBottom < 40) { // highlight the last section
            i = sections.length-1;
        }
        links.removeClass('active');
        var active = sections.eq(i).attr('id');
        links.filter('[href="#'+active+'"]').addClass('active');
    }).trigger('scroll');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRcjc/3/ http://jsfiddle.net/GRcjc/3/show

Comment: Hey Stano,
Thanks a lot for your help. 
I have tried to implement it but it doesn't seem to be working on my page but I can't figure out why. Here is a [link](http://lookwhatjuliendid.com/projects/lwjd/) to the actual page. Would you mind having a quick look, I imagine this is just something small. (note that the "#navigation" is only shown when the page in <900px). Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, you're using old jQuery1.6, and so in your console appears the message `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`, either change the `$(window).on('scroll', function(e){` to `$(window).scroll(function(e){` or use newer jQuery [1.7+](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated to 1.7 and the error seems to be gone but it still doesn't work...Can it be related to where the script is?

Comment: The script tried to highlight sections, that are not present in your menu. Use this selector instead: `var sections = $('#resume,#design,#contact');` This should work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about a plugin to minimize your work??
http://scrollnav.com/
=)

Comment: That is not an answer to his question, he already implemented something and needs help getting it to work.

Comment: Hey Igor. Thanks for the tip.
My navigation being only for Mobile & Tablet + being only 2 links I was hoping I could find a simple way to do it and this template seemed to be a great solution...